# Jasper Reports Backward Compatibility

Tags: jasper-reports, version, compatibility, ireport

I was using the 3.7.4 version of jasper reports library and i am planning to upgrade it to 5.6.1 which is the latest version and supports dynamic row generation for outcoming reports.
But there exists a lot of jrxml templates in my db which are prepared to use with jasper reports 3.7.4.

Is 5.6.1 provides compatibility to reports those currently works with the version 3.7.4? Or can i do something practical to make them work with 5.7.1 version?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a newer version of iReport, it creates new jrxml tags like UUID etc which are not valid in previous versions. Also the jasper file (.jrxml or .japser) produced by iReport is not usable with an older version of JasperReports (or at least it is not guaranteed to work). So you can end up to screw up your report.

This is in Jaspersoft roadmap in future releases but no idea when this be fixed and released.